# why the float element will not be calculated as part of div height?BFC can!Where the CSS specification said?

Tags: html, css

I know float element is not the normal flow.But where the Specification said the not-normal flow will not be calculated as part of height of parent box.I search this in [css1.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#formatting-model) and [css2.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/)

When the parent box become BFC（block formatting context) the float element will be calculated as part of the BFC . But ,i also can not find where the specification said float element will be calculated as part.

I am confused by this question for many years ,even i know the BFC can solve the height collapse of div.But ,i don't know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification that says that ordinary containing blocks do not grow in height to enclose their floats is inferred from the statement in CSS 2.2 [9.5 Floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#floats) where it says:

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not exist.

Plus what Neeraj has already said:[10.6.3 Block-level non-replaced elements in normal flow when 'overflow' computes to 'visible'](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#normal-block)

> Only children in the normal flow are taken into account (i.e., floating boxes and absolutely positioned boxes are ignored, and relatively positioned boxes are considered without their offset).

The part of the specification that requires BFCs to contain the float is CSS 2.2 [10.6.7 'Auto' heights for block formatting context roots](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#root-height) where it says:

> In addition, if the element has any floating descendants whose bottom margin edge is below the element's bottom content edge, then the height is increased to include those edges. Only floats that participate in this block formatting context are taken into account, e.g., floats inside absolutely positioned descendants or other floats are not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link from the specification:
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#normal-block

Check the last paragraph:

> Only children in the normal flow are taken into account (i.e.,
>   floating boxes and absolutely positioned boxes are ignored, and
>   relatively positioned boxes are considered without their offset). Note
>   that the child box may be an anonymous block box.

Answer (score 0):

If you set height for the parent div, the child float element considers the parent height normally. The trick is **you have to set a height for the div**. If the div height is relative (by percentage) then the parent of the div must have an explicit height set.

```
<div style="background: red; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <div style="background: green; width: 50%; height: 50%; float: left;">
        1
    </div>
    <div style="background: blue; width: 50%; height: 75%; float: left;">
        2
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nvxnkb99/1/).

Answer (score 0):

If your question is why, then the answer is the floating content may be larger in height than the container it's in. Take a floating img in a block, then when the text of the block all fits to the side of the img, any text following the block will also have to be in the same flow; otherwise it would behave as if the following block would clear the float.

A concrete example: In the following snippet, the first div is 95 pixels high (five lines) on my monitor, even if the img inside is larger. If the floating img were also taken into account rather than only the non-floating content, the second div would start 190 pixels down rather than where it does now.

```css
div {font:16px/19px 'Arial', sans-serif}
div img {float:left}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x190" alt="▒">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
     consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
     magna aliqua.</div>
<div>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
     ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
     esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Hope this clears things up!